# search only lines with exact string in a column

Tags: awk

example input file (tab delimited columns):

```
1ea73495-490d-6dda-9b30-afa37288d418    00627   a1
1ea73495-490d-6dda-9b30-afa37288d418    006273  a2
1ea73495-490d-6dda-9b30-afa37288d418    000627  a3
1ea73495-4b42-6ee8-98fc-338d6d9414f1    00673   a4
```

I need to find all lines where second column is either 00627 or 00673.
Following command I get all lines:

```
$ awk -F$'\t' -vu="00627|00673" '$2~u' input
1ea73495-490d-6dda-9b30-afa37288d418    00627   a1
1ea73495-490d-6dda-9b30-afa37288d418    006273  a2
1ea73495-490d-6dda-9b30-afa37288d418    000627  a3
1ea73495-4b42-6ee8-98fc-338d6d9414f1    00673   a4
```

and following commands fails:

```
$ awk -F$'\t' -vu="00627|00673" '$2~^u$' input
awk: cmd. line:1: $2~^u$
awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ syntax error
$ awk -F$'\t' -vu="00627|00673" '$2~^(u)$' input
awk: cmd. line:1: $2~^(u)$
awk: cmd. line:1:    ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:2: $2~^(u)$
awk: cmd. line:2:         ^ unexpected newline or end of string
$ awk -F$'\t' -vu="00627|00673" '$2~/^(u)$/' input
$
```

Update: I have found solution using shell variable:

```
$ list="00627|00673"
$ awk -F$'\t' -vu="00627|00673" '$2~/^('"$list"')$/' input
1ea73495-490d-6dda-9b30-afa37288d418    00627   a1
1ea73495-4b42-6ee8-98fc-338d6d9414f1    00673   a4
$
```

Comment: If you want an exact match, don't use `~`.  Use `==` instead.

Comment: unfortunatelly, with == nothing is returned: awk -F$'\t' -vu="00627|00673" '$2==u' input

Answer (score 1):

You need to restrict the regex.  It's not the best solution, but you could do:

```
awk -v u='^00627$|^00673$' '$2~u' input
```

Another option is:

```
awk -v u='00627|00673' 'BEGIN{split(u, a, "|"); for(i in a) {b[a[i]] = 1}} $2 in b ' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^(00627|00673)$/'
```

or

```
awk '{ if ($2 ~ /^(00627|00673)$/) print }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution using shell variable:

```
$ list="00627|00673"
$ awk -F$'\t' -vu="00627|00673" '$2~/^('"$list"')$/' input
1ea73495-490d-6dda-9b30-afa37288d418    00627   a1
1ea73495-4b42-6ee8-98fc-338d6d9414f1    00673   a4
$
```

The solution given by William is also ok but I get the list automatically as in example, delimited with pipe.